# How to get the value of the variables from an external txt file

Tags: python, text

I have this txt file:

```
#internal radius of the stator
r_int_stat=0.34
#axial coordinate of the beginning of the rotor
rotor_in=0.1289
#axial coordinate of the end of the rotor
rotor_end=0.173
#internal radius of the rotor
r_int_rot=0.32
#axial coordinate of the end of the domain
end=0.306
#external radius
r_ext=0.4
```

I want to create a Python script who recalls this txt file and uses that variables. I have this Python code:

```
file=open("testfile.dat","w")
file.write("Header\n")
file.write("\n")
if curve==1:
     file.write("XYZ polyline\n")
     file.write("2\n")
     #the z coordinate remains always zero because I have an axysimmetric mesh
     file.write('0 '+str(r_int_stat)+' 0\n')
     file.write(str(rotor_in)+' '+str(r_int_stat)+' 0\n')
     file.write('\n')
     file.write('XYZ polyline\n')
     file.write('2\n')
     file.write(str(rotor_in)+' '+str(r_int_stat)+' 0\n')
     file.write(str(rotor_end)+' '+str(r_int_rot)+' 0\n')
     file.write('\n')
     file.write('XYZ polyline\n')
     file.write('2\n')
     file.write(str(rotor_end)+' '+str(r_int_rot)+' 0\n')
     file.write(str(end)+' '+str(r_int_rot)+' 0\n')
     file.write('\n')
     file.write('XYZ polyline\n')
     file.write('2\n')
     file.write(str(end)+' '+str(r_int_rot)+' 0\n')
     file.write(str(end)+' '+str(r_ext)+' 0\n')
     file.write('\n')
     file.write('XYZ polyline\n')
     file.write('2\n')
     file.write(str(end)+' '+str(r_ext)+' 0\n')
     file.write('0 '+str(r_ext)+' 0\n')
     file.write('\n')
     file.write('XYZ polyline\n')
     file.write('2\n')
     file.write('0 '+str(r_ext)+' 0\n')
     file.write('0 '+str(r_int_stat)+' 0\n')

else:
     file.write("XYZ cspline\n")
     file.write("5\n")


file.close()
```

I want this Python code to take the value of the variables from the txt file because I need to modify these variables, so it's easier from an external txt file.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're probably better off using a more convenient storage approach like JSON, CSV, pickle or a database like sqlite3 as a starting point. Your code is very verbose for writing the outputs, before you even try reading it back in.

Comment: Maybe look at [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)

Answer (score 0):

Following Mr Dietsche's suggestion, use `Configparser`. (If he answers please let me know and I will delete this answer.)

First alter that file by putting one line at the beginning.

```
[parameters]
#internal radius of the stator
r_int_stat=0.34
#axial coordinate of the beginning of the rotor
rotor_in=0.1289
#axial coordinate of the end of the rotor
rotor_end=0.173
#internal radius of the rotor
r_int_rot=0.32
#axial coordinate of the end of the domain
end=0.306
#external radius
r_ext=0.4
```

The following Python code suggests how you can extract its contents.

Open the configuration file, ask what its sections are (in your case there's just one), get the dictionary of the contents of that section, and display the dictionary.

```
>>> import configparser
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read('testfile.dat')
['testfile.dat']
>>> config.sections()
['parameters']
>>> d = config['parameters']
>>> for key, value in d.items():
...     key, value
...     
('r_int_stat', '0.34')
('rotor_in', '0.1289')
('rotor_end', '0.173')
('r_int_rot', '0.32')
('end', '0.306')
('r_ext', '0.4')
```

Comment: You're most welcome! On StackOverflow, when someone gives you a satisfactory solution you can mark it 'accepted'.